Could not find method reactNativeArchitectures() for arguments [] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkOptions
updated some packages versions, for example:
`"react-native": "0.73.6"` (from 0.70)

`classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.1")` (from 7.2.1)

`classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1")` (from 4.3.13)

ERROR:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file 'C:\Lavoro\GitHub\ePublic\LaMiaCitta\android\app\build.gradle' line: 163

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.



Could not find method reactNativeArchitectures() for arguments [] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkOptions.

line 163 (abifilters):
if (!enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture) {
    ndk {
        abiFilters (*reactNativeArchitectures())
    }
}

I can't find any solution...
